# How to see debug console when app installed through apk in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am able to see debug console in the terminal when I am run the command `flutter run`

but when I run the command `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`
it's given me two application
so when I am installing one of this apk in my android phone, I am not able to see any debug output or my print.

I want to know how can I do this because my app is working fine in debug mode but when I installed `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` this apk, my app crash after two or three pages because of an external plugin.

How can I check debug console when I am installed the app through apk?

Comment: I think you can't. Check here how to run and test on real device https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#set-up-your-android-device

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`flutter attach`

and then start your application. Or using adb logcat:

`adb logcat *:S flutter:V`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after `flutter attach` and start application  terminal stuck on "Waiting for a connection from Flutter on ASUS X00TD..."

Comment: @yash You can also use adb logcat: `adb logcat *:S flutter:V`

Comment: dude adb option is soo cool that I danced for this find