# Flutter: Widgets are missing in release build and showing grey screen

Tags: flutter

in one of my Flutter files I have this code that theoretically doesn't seem it should be a problem to run at all. It renders nicely in the debug version but when I build a release iOS and Android app files, it becomes partly invisible. There's a widget inside listview.builder which renders CheckboxListTile. yet this one doesn't render and neither does any widget afterwards.Console is not showing any errors
Following is the widget where I face error

```
ListView.builder(
                      physics: const ScrollPhysics(parent: null),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (cont, index) {
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                          value: value.selected_box.contains(index),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            // print(val);
                            value.selectedCat(value.categories![index]['id']);
                            value.update(index);
                          },
                          title: Text(value.categories![index]['title']),
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: value.categories!.length,
                    );
```

[image]

above image is from release mode below is the expected result in release mode
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see a grey screen after building your app, it means there is some error on it. The grey screen is the very same red screen with yellow letters that you can see while debugging your app, but on some occasions, this red screen is not displayed since the error does not break the app in debug, but it does break the app after a build.

Therefore you should check your logs in debug, you are probably missing an error that does not break your app in debug, but it does in the release.

Comment: my console is not showing any errors or any exceptions

Comment: You can try seeing the logs for your app build, so this way you know what is provoking these errors in the build and not in the debug version.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58693539/how-to-see-debug-console-when-app-installed-through-apk-in-flutter) can help

Comment: there is no errors in release version too so I build release apk from android studio it worked but from when I build release apk from vs code it dint work I don't know why but thanks for response